# putting the fizz back into beer

Tags: beer, yeast, sugar

I'm hopping you guys can help me with this one. I want to fill a 2lt coke bottle with beer from bottles and add sugar and yeast to put the CO2 back in so it will last 8 to 10 days plus.

I'm after advice on if it will work and what amount of sugar/yeast for 2lt container.

If you want to know why it's i go to crete every year and they don't sell bitter only larger and I cant put glass in the hold luggage and if I just put it in the 2lt bottle the beer will only last 2-3 days before it goes flat :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can [use a beer priming-sugar calculator to determine the correct amount](http://www.brewersfriend.com/beer-priming-calculator/). For 2L of beer, which probably already has ~2 volumes of CO₂, you probably only need 3-5g of table sugar and just a sprinkle of yeast, and then you're mostly just going to presurize the vessel instead of really carbonating the beer itself. If you let the beer go flat, first, assume it has more like 0.5-0.8 volumes of CO₂ remaining. You'll definitely need to add yeast, as Denny mentions. And, yes, a carbonator cap would be an even better approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you use commercial beer it probably won't work.  The beer will likely be filtered which will remove most of all of the yeast so more sugar won't recarb it.  You could use a carbonator cap and CO2 to do what you want, though.

Comment: The question specifically mentions adding yeast along with the sugar so it should work with *any* beer s/he chooses.

Answer (score 1):

The yeast will likely change the character of the beer. Quick solution would be to go with the [carbonation drops](http://www.morebeer.com/products/carbonation-drops.html). You might also consider a [draft box](http://www.northernbrewer.com/shop/brewing/kegging/draft-boxes/beerbox-portable-homebrew-dispenser.html) which allows for a CO2 cartridge to carbonate the beer.